# separate XML results into 2+ groups using XSL

Tags: xslt

I'm having trouble creating the XSLT to do something that I think should be straightforward...

Given the following XML:

```
<DATA_DS>
<LIST_ITEMS>
    <ITEMS>
        <abc>2011</abc>
        <def>ABC Company</def>
        <value>23</value>
    </ITEMS>
    <ITEMS>
        <abc>2011</abc>
        <def>ABC Company 1</def>
        <value>11</value>
    </ITEMS>    
    <ITEMS>
        <abc>2010</abc>
        <def>ABC Company 2</def>
        <value>15</value>
    </ITEMS>            
    <ITEMS>
        <abc>2010</abc>
        <def>ABC Company 3</def>
        <value>6</value>
    </ITEMS>
    <ITEMS>
        <abc>2010</abc>
        <def>ABC Company 4</def>
        <value>44</value>
    </ITEMS>                
</LIST_ITEMS></DATA_DS>
```

how would I go about transforming it using XSLT into something like this:

```
<table>
    <row>23</row>
    <row>11</row>
</table>

<table>
    <row>15</row>
    <row>6</row>
    <row>44</row>
</table>
```

the idea is to create a new "table" every time a new "abc" is encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xslt 2.0 instruction `for-each-group` is what you are looking for.

Following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="DATA_DS/LIST_ITEMS/ITEMS" group-by="abc">
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <row>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()/value" />
                        </row>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
    <table>
        <row>23</row>
        <row>11</row>
    </table>
    <table>
        <row>15</row>
        <row>6</row>
        <row>44</row>
    </table>
</output>
```

Comment: I had looked at for-each-group but I just needed to see a good example to understand it. Thanks!